# retrieve data from mysql and email it

Tags: php, mysql, email, select

I have a php page which displays class schedule data for each user from mysql database like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='0'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Class Link</th>
        <th>Student Skype ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Faculty Name</th>
        <th>Class Name</th>
        <th>USA Date (DD/MM/YY)</th>
        <th>USA Start Time</th>
        <th>USA End Time</th>
        <th>India Date (DD/MM/YY)</th>
        <th>India Start Time</th>
        <th>India End Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"".$row['class_link']."\" target='blank'>Start Class</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['skype_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['faculty_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['starttime'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['endtime'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['facdate'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['facstarttime'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['facendtime'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

now i have the following php email script

```
$to = 'support@xyz.com';
$subject = "Your Class Schedule";
$message = **'HOW CAN I PUT THE DATA FROM MYSQL HERE?'**;
$headers = 'From: REPLY@XYZ.COM' . "\r\n" .
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
$headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: REPLY@XYZ.COM' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As mentioned in the $message of the above code i would like to put this retrieved data into the $ message section so that it goes in the mail..

can anyone help?

Comment: You already fetched your rows with `mysql_fetch_array()`. Just concatenate in or interpolate in the variable: `$message = "Some text {$row['col_from_db']}";`

Comment: Michael, i have multiple rows popping up when i run the search, how can i feed them all into the message section? + i would also like to keep the tabular formatting intact when it goes in email..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on the source of your mysql data and how it is stored can't you retrieve it and just add it to the $message variable?

```
<?PHP
    $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE youridentifier = 'unique'"
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $content = $row['field with email content']
        // or if there is more than one field
        $content2 = $row['field with more email content']
    }
    // then you can create the "message" as you wish
    $message = "Greetings ".$content.",

        you are receiving this email because of blah. ".$content2."

        Thank you,
        code guy"
    // Then you can still use $message as your variable
}
?>
```

format it as you with (HTML or not, etc) .. and mail away.

for multiple rows change the while up a little..

```
<?PHP
    // give your message the starting string
    $message = 'Greetings,

        you are receiving this email as an invoice as follows:
        <table style="width: 80%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Cost</td>
                <td>Weight</td>
                <td>Color</td>
            </tr>
    '
    $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE youridentifier = 'unique'"
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $message .= "        <tr>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['itemdescription']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['cost']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['shippingweight']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['color']."</td>";
        $message .= "        </tr>";
    }
    // then update the message with the ending
    $message .= "
        </table>

        Thank you,
        code guy"
    // Then you can still use $message as your variable
}
?>
```

That pressumption is if you are using HTML formatted emails, otherwise it'll just be formatted text.