# How to add SELECT statement to MySQL email

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have the script below:

```
$to      = 'jackal@sbccrew.com';
$subject = 'Submission from the website!';
$message = 'Please check out the latest submission';
$query= 'SELECT name,phone,needs,specifics FROM contact order by ID ASC limit 1';
$headers = 'From: info@preferredmobiletinting.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@preferredmobiletinting.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $query, $headers);

exit;
```

When I receive this email, I only see the message, not the actual query I put in there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect to see `$query` in your email?

Comment: The fourth parameter for `mail()` is the headers. You need to add `$query` to `$message` before you send it, and remove `$query` from the `mail()` call.

Comment: this is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for the mail function.... you can't just attach a query....?  you're not even running it anywhere?  you have to run the query and attach it as a string with the message.  i would format it, too... (you can't just pass the resource or array in there, either)

Comment: `$query` is just a string. It might contain SQL, but PHP doesn't know that. PHp doesn't know what SQL is - it's just text. You need to CONNECT to a database, send over that query, execute it, retrieve results, blah blah blah.

Comment: [this is a very good SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900190/623952) about how to do what you're trying to do.. or did you get confused with [SQL Server's mail function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) that does allow query attachments like that...?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to add the query into the message?  If so you should just add it to the message:

```
$message .= 'SELECT name,phone,needs,specifics FROM contact order by ID ASC limit 1';
```

Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  I suggest taking a look at the documentation for the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what they are trying to do... (unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

The third argument in the `mail()` function is reserved for the contents of the email. You are passing the `$query` variable in the fourth argument position which is reserved for headers. If you are trying to see the query in the email text you need to concatenate it to your message variable:

```
$message = 'Please check out the latest submission';
$message .= 'SELECT name,phone,needs,specifics FROM contact order by ID ASC limit 1';
```

Comment: I think the `<br/>`s are in there because the OP didn't know how to format markdown.